# How to map an array to a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array.prototype.map

I have this array with 3 integers. I want to use these integers and make a new array of objects that populate the y variable. I want to have the x as an id variable. How can I do this?

**From:**

```
const arr = [6, 9, 2]
```

**To:**

```
const arrOfObjects = [{x: 1, y: 6}, {x: 2, y: 9}, {x: 3, y: 2}]
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. In particular see the `map` method on arrays, which provides both the value and its index. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Could you use the array index (or index+1) as the id variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
const arr = [6, 9, 2];

const newArray = arr.map((value,index) => ({x:index + 1, y:value }));

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: You may also want to link to the [documentation for `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).